# Only one record with a TRUNCATE INSERT queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a query. Indeed, i want to truncate a table and then insert data into this same table.

My problem : When i execute these 2 queries the INSERT records only one row and i don't know why. When i execute the INSERT query without the TRUNCATE before it works fine. What can i do to combine TRUNCATE and then INSERT ?

Thanks

Here is the code :

```
    <?php
    $base = mysql_connect ("***", "***", "***");
    mysql_select_db ('***', $base) ;
    $vider = "TRUNCATE TABLE drag";
    mysql_query($vider);        
    // accept JSON parameter (and Un-quote string if needed)
    $p = stripslashes($_REQUEST['p']);
    // decode JSON object (it shouldn't be decoded as associative array)
    $arr = json_decode($p);
    // open loop through each array element
    foreach ($arr as $p){
        // set id, row index and cell index
        $id = $p[0];
        $row = $p[1];
        $cell = $p[2];
        // instead of print, you can store accepted parameteres to the database
        print "Id=$id Row=$row Cell=$cell<br>";
        $ajout = "INSERT INTO drag VALUES('','$id','$row','$cell')";
        mysql_query($ajout);
        mysql_close($base);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should remove the mysql_close from the foreach() loop.

You are closing the database connection after the first insert. The next queries will do nothing

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to put `mysql_close()` outside of the loop. Otherwise, you cannot send subsequent queries without `mysql_connect` again.

```
<?php
    $base = mysql_connect ("***", "***", "***");
    mysql_select_db ('***', $base) ;
    $vider = "TRUNCATE TABLE drag";
    mysql_query($vider);        
    // accept JSON parameter (and Un-quote string if needed)
    $p = stripslashes($_REQUEST['p']);
    // decode JSON object (it shouldn't be decoded as associative array)
    $arr = json_decode($p);
    // open loop through each array element
    foreach ($arr as $p){
        // set id, row index and cell index
        $id = $p[0];
        $row = $p[1];
        $cell = $p[2];
        // instead of print, you can store accepted parameteres to the database
        print "Id=$id Row=$row Cell=$cell<br>";
        $ajout = "INSERT INTO drag VALUES('','$id','$row','$cell')";
        mysql_query($ajout);
    }

    mysql_close($base);
?>
```

But **STOP**! Don't use `mysql_query()` anymore. See the big red box at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php? Switch to MySQLi or PDO instead.